# Python function reference being passed into constructor turns into c_void_p datatype

Tags: python, ctypes, curses

To make a long story short, I'm trying to pass a list of dictionaries into a container class, with the intention that each dictionary will be used to instantiate another class. The problem is that each dictionary contains a function object reference to be assigned to the subclass, and for some reason just before the innermost subclass is instantiated, it changes from a python function object into a c_void_p object.

The application domain is the creation of a library of text-based UI widgets using curses.

Here is the 'child' class which the container is meant to contain:

```
class DigitalReadout(Window):
    # Just a one-line borderless window displaying some data...
    def __init__(self, width, y, x, label, digits, data_source, parent=None):

        super(DigitalReadout, self).__init__(1, width, y, x, parent)

        self.data_source = data_source
        self.data = self.get_data_from_source()
        self.label = label
        self.digits = digits
        self.spaces = self.width - len(self.label) - self.digits # Calc Number of extra spaces

    ###Irrelevant display-related classes omitted###

    def update_data(self):
        self.data = self.get_data_from_source() #return data from function

    def get_data_from_source(self):
        return self.data_source.__call__()
```

And here is the 'container' class:

```
class ReadoutPanel(BoxedWindow):

    def __init__(self, y, x, readouts, parent=None):

        super(ReadoutPanel,self).__init__(2 + len(readouts), self.find_longest_readout_width(readouts) + 2, y, x, parent)
        self.children = []
        self.initialize_readouts(readouts)

    def find_longest_readout_width(self, readouts):
        #Find the longest member and size container accordingly
        longest_length = 0
        for each_dict in readouts:
            this_dict_length = each_dict['digits'] + len(each_dict['label']) + 1
            if this_dict_length > longest_length:
                longest_length = this_dict_length
        return longest_length

    def initialize_readouts(self, readouts):
        y_readout_index = 1
        for each_hash in readouts:
            function = each_dict['func']
            function()
            self.children.append(DigitalReadout(each_dict['digits'] + len(each_dict['label']) + 1,
                                                1,
                                                y_readout_index,
                                                1,
                                                function,
                                                self.window))
```

For reference, the base classes Window and BoxedWindow can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/1666089)

When I run the following test code, I get the subsequent error:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #standard cuses initialization here...

    from time import clock

    i = 0

    def print_i():
        return str(i)

    readouts = [{'label': 'count',
                 'digits': 10,
                 'func': print_i},
                {'label': 'clock',
                 'digits':10,
                 'func': print_i}]

    readout_panel = ReadoutPanel(1, 1, readouts) #Initialize that puppy!


    curses.endwin()
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "window.py", line 515, in <module>
 readout_panel = ReadoutPanel(1, 1, readouts)
 File "window.py", line 455, in __init__
 self.initialize_readouts(readouts)
 File "window.py", line 476, in initialize_readouts
 self.window))
 File "window.py", line 183, in __init__
 self.data = self.data_source()
 TypeError: 'c_void_p' object is not callable
```

Printlining reveals that the function is being fetched from the dictionary and is still a function object. Once it gets passed into the constructor for DigitalReadout, however, it somehow comes back a c_void_p object.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the horrendously long question.

Comment: Am I missing something here? You are passing 6 values to `DigitalReadout` with 5th being `function`. According to `__init__` of `DigitalReadout`, 5th parameter is `digits`, not `data_source`. So you are trying to do `self.window()`, not `function()`.

Comment: Egads I feel so moronic. Thank you for taking the time to point this out, it makes me glad despite the foolishness of the error.

Comment: @RobWouters: Wow, I didn't see your answer there. You made my comment obsolete but got yourself an up-vote from me :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the constructor of `DigitalReadout`:

```
def __init__(self, width, y, x, label, digits, data_source, parent=None)
```

This is how you call it:

```
DigitalReadout(each_dict['digits'] + len(each_dict['label']) + 1, # width
                                        1,                        # y
                                        y_readout_index,          # x
                                        1,                        # label
                                        function,                 # digits
                                        self.window)              # data_source
```

Looks like you're missing a parameter in the constructor (`height?`), because if I'm reading it right, the function should be `data_source` and it now is `digits`.

Comment: Good god man, you're right. God bless you for helping the severely cognitively impaired such as myself, I will not forget this!